# Passing in type as parameter does not work in production in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, electron, electron-builder, typescript-decorator

I am having an issue passing types around in TypeScript. The following works fine in development, but issues arise when building to production.
The main issue is with my ForeignKey decorator as I am making my own little ORM and I need to pass the type to the function, which is working for development.

```
@Table("Customer")
class Customer
{
    ...

    @ForeignKey(() => Room, Relations.OneToOneForced, "roomId")
    room?: Room;
}
```

And the ForeignKey Decorator:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

const ForeignKey = <T>(type: () => Constructor<T>, relation: Relations, idKey?: string): PropertyDecorator =>
{
    return (target, property) =>
    {
        let metadata = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(MetadataKey, target.constructor) as Metadata || undefined;

        const fk: IForeignKey = {
            key: property,
            type,
            relation
        };
        ...
        Reflect.defineMetadata(MetadataKey, metadata, target.constructor);
    };
};
```

However the type itself does not log as a function like I would expect. As a result, I see:

```
()=>s["Room"]
()=>a["Employee"]
()=>i["Department"]
()=>i["Customer"]
```

Or whatever type I am using. In development, I would see that actual constructor function printed out and not whatever this is. I have been digging around in TypeORM and class-transformer source code to see how they are doing this, but I appears to be handled in the same fashion.
I am trying to build to electron using Vue-electron-builder alongside webpack, as it is bundled with Vue-Cli 3.

Is this an issue with my code? Is it a webpack issue? I have no idea what is going on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What output would you expect? Where are you logging and what are you logging here? Chances are that the minification of the source is an issue. Your problem is unclear, though. A minimal working example would probably help.

Comment: I was expecting a console output of a class function. When I was logging the type of the code in production, it is still a typeof Function but when I call it, It returns an empty class, not the class of type I was expecting.

Comment: Class names could be minified, would recommend looking into that. Some bundlers can be configured to leave class names as they are. Another question is what JS version you compile to...

Comment: Have you looked at the compiled code? Could be useful.